# Bootstrap popover change full background

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I try to change the popover background color, I get the problem that not the full popover is using that background ( The triangle pointing to the speaker):

[image]

My css:

```
.popover-content {
    background-color: #FCD086;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Most probably the triangle is done by pseudo element :after. So you need to inspect that and change the styling of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change this css too:

```
    .popover.top .arrow:after {
      bottom: 1px;
      margin-left: -10px;
      border-top-color: #FCD086; /*<----here*/
      border-bottom-width: 0;
      content: " ";
    }
```

Comment: I'd leave off the `.top` so it works no matter which direction the popover opens in.